# How to solve a multipart exception in spring bootusing dropbox api?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dropbox

I use the following mapping:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
        public String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestParam("filePath") String filePath) throws Exception {
            ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
            Metadata uploadMetaData = dropboxClient.files().uploadBuilder(filePath).uploadAndFinish(inputStream);
            logger.info("upload meta data =====> {}", uploadMetaData.toString());
            inputStream.close();
            return "You successfully uploaded " + filePath + "!!";
        }
```

When I execute it, then I receive the following error: `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request`

Do you know how I can solve this and why I receive the error?

Answer (score 0):

Add enctype="multipart/form-data" to your form

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I actually have no form or html as I am using spring boot. Where can I do it there?

Comment: Well if you are not using html, i'm assuming you are using some software to make http post request to /upload, you should change enctype in the sofware